# apply two functions to the two halves of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to find how to apply two functions to a numpy array each one only on half the values.
Here is the code I have been trying

```
def hybrid_array(xs,height,center,fwhh):
    xs[xs<=center] = height*np.exp((-(xs[xs<=center]-center)**2)/(2*(fwhh/(2*np.sqrt(2*np.log(2))))**2))
    xs[xs>center] = height*1/(np.abs(1+((center-xs[xs>center])/(fwhh/2))**2))
    return xs
```

However I am overwriting the initial array that is passed to the argument. The usual trick of copying it with a slice ie. the following still changes b.

```
a = b[:]
c = hybrid_array(a,args)
```

If there is a better way of doing any part of what I am trying, I would be very grateful if you could let me know as I am still new to numpy arrays.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [copy.deepcopy](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) to copy the array `b` onto `a` before calling your function.

```
import copy
a = copy.deepcopy(b)
c = hybrid_array(a,args)
```

Alternatively, you can use the copy method of the array

```
a = b.copy()
c = hybrid_array(a,args)
```

Note***

You may be wondering, why despite an easier way to copy an array with the copy method of numpy array I introduced the copy.deepcopy. Other's may disagree but here is my reasoning

1. Using the method deepcopy makes it clear that you are intending to do a deepcopy instead of reference copy
2. All python's data type do not support the copy method. Numpy has it and good it has but when you are programming with numpy and python you may end up using various numpy and non numpy data types not all of which would support the copy method. To remain consistent I would prefer to use the first.

Comment: deepcopy sounds like a better idea to me too. Thank you for your help

Comment: Since a NumPy array doesn't contain references, it's a bit pointless to talk about a deep or shallow copy -- either it's a copy or not, but any further disambiguation is meaningless.  Using `deepcopy()` is slower, especially for smaller arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Copying a NumPy array `a` is done with `a.copy()`.  In your application, however, there is no need to copy the old data.  All you need is a new array of the same shape and dtype as the old one.  You can use

```
result = numpy.empty_like(xs)
```

to create such an array.  If you generally don't want your function to modify its parameter, you should do this inside the function, rather than requiring the caller to take care of this.

Comment: could you please elaborate, I don't understand how you could use this. Thank you

Comment: @Anake: You would use this by copying the line of code to the beginning of your function, and then use `result` as the result.  Exactly what part of this is unclear?

Comment: sorry about that, didn't realise the implication of slowing the system by copying the array. I understand now, thanks